# Using x509 Certs with Apache Curator

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Is it possible to use x509 certs for authentication with zookeeper via the curator project? I've looked through the curator project and did not see any reference to x509.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Curator is a wrapper around the standard ZooKeeper client so there's nothing particular to Curator about this. Set up the x509 provider on the ZooKeeper servers and set the correct authorization when creating your Curator client

Comment: @Randgalt the documentation seems to refer to schemes in that sense: https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/framework/CuratorFrameworkFactory.Builder.html#authorization-java.lang.String-byte:A-. Wouldn't this refer to digest, el at? How would you add the x509 to the authorization in the builder?

Comment: That forwards directly to the ZooKeeper API: ZooKeeper#addAuthInfo() - so it's not Curator specific.